# Use Esper variable to grow and shrink a time window

Tags: esper

I have a time window and a variable that is the parameter to the time window.

```
CREATE VARIABLE int expireSecs = 10;
SELECT * FROM Event#time(expireSecs sec);
```

In the code I call to set the expireSecs value.

```
epRuntime.setVariableValue("expireSecs", 5);
```

The time window doesn't seems to go from 10 seconds to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression-window and expression-batch-window are the only windows that re-evaluate parameters expressions continuously. The time window does not re-evaluate. The documentation has this [here](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.1.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-parameters). There is an example in the expression-window [description](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.1.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#view-win-expr), in this way.

```
select * from MyEvent#expr(oldest_timestamp > newest_timestamp - (1000*expirySec))
```